# How do I read a vector of a generic type with an arbitrary separator and an optional limit from all possible streams?

Tags: vector, rust, stdin

I want to write a function `read_vector` which should read and parse items of type `T` from stdin and return a vector containing these items. If the delimiter is `'\n'` it should parse lines, otherwise all items are supposed to be in one line separated by the delimiter. If the count is not `None`, then it represents the number of items to be read.

The goal is to minimize code-duplication and create a general function without restrictions on types or whatever else.

However, I run into a problem which I cannot understand at all. This code:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn read_line() -> String {
    let mut buf = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut buf)
        .expect("failed to read a line");
    buf
}

fn parse_iter<'a, Iter, Value>(mut iter: Iter) -> Vec<Value>
where
    Iter: std::iter::Iterator<Item = &'a str>,
    Value: std::str::FromStr,
    <Value as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    iter.map(|x| x.parse().expect("failed to parse")).collect()
}

fn read_vector<T>(count: Option<usize>, delimiter: char) -> Vec<T>
where
    T: std::str::FromStr,
    <T as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    match count {
        None => match delimiter {
            '\n' => parse_iter(io::stdin().lock().lines().map(|x| x.unwrap())),
            _ => parse_iter(read_line().split(delimiter)),
        },
        _ => match delimiter {
            '\n' => parse_iter(
                io::stdin()
                    .lock()
                    .lines()
                    .map(|x| x.unwrap())
                    .take(count.unwrap()),
            ),
            _ => parse_iter(read_line().split(delimiter).take(count.unwrap())),
        },
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vector: Vec<u32> = read_vector(None, '\n');
}
```

leads to these errors:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<[closure@src/main.rs:27:63: 27:77] as std::ops::FnOnce<(std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::io::Error>,)>>::Output == &str`
  --> src/main.rs:27:21
   |
27 |             '\n' => parse_iter(io::stdin().lock().lines().map(|x| x.unwrap())),
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found &str
   |
   = note: expected type `std::string::String`
              found type `&str`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::Iterator` for `std::iter::Map<std::io::Lines<std::io::StdinLock<'_>>, [closure@src/main.rs:27:63: 27:77]>`
   = note: required by `parse_iter`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<[closure@src/main.rs:35:26: 35:40] as std::ops::FnOnce<(std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::io::Error>,)>>::Output == &str`
  --> src/main.rs:31:21
   |
31 |             '\n' => parse_iter(
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found &str
   |
   = note: expected type `std::string::String`
              found type `&str`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::Iterator` for `std::iter::Map<std::io::Lines<std::io::StdinLock<'_>>, [closure@src/main.rs:35:26: 35:40]>`
   = note: required by `parse_iter`
```

How can I fix the problem?

It would be nice to see not only the fix to the problem but also advice on how to improve current implementation, because it still contains many code-repetitions and works only with Stdin instead of all possible streams.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};


fn read_line<T>(mut stream: T) -> String
where
    T: BufRead,
{
    let mut buf = String::new();
    stream.read_line(&mut buf).expect("failed to read a line");
    buf
}


fn read_line_from_stdin() -> String {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let stdin = stdin.lock();
    read_line(stdin)
}


fn parse_slice_iter<'a, Iter, Value>(iter: Iter) -> Vec<Value>
where
    Iter: std::iter::Iterator<Item = &'a str>,
    Value: std::str::FromStr,
    <Value as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    iter.map(|x| x.trim().parse().expect("failed to parse"))
        .collect()
}


fn parse_string_iter<'a, Iter, Value>(iter: Iter) -> Vec<Value>
where
    Iter: std::iter::Iterator<Item = String>,
    Value: std::str::FromStr,
    <Value as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    iter.map(|x| x.parse().expect("failed to parse")).collect()
}


fn read_vector<T, S>(count: Option<usize>, delimiter: char, stream: S) -> Vec<T>
where
    T: std::str::FromStr,
    <T as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Debug,
    S: BufRead,
{
    match count {
        None => match delimiter {
            '\n' => parse_string_iter(stream.lines().map(|x| x.unwrap())),
            _ => parse_slice_iter(read_line(stream).split(delimiter)),
        },
        _ => match delimiter {
            '\n' => parse_string_iter(stream.lines().take(count.unwrap()).map(|x| x.unwrap())),
            _ => parse_slice_iter(read_line(stream).split(delimiter).take(count.unwrap())),
        },
    }
}


fn read_vector_from_stdin<T>(count: Option<usize>, delimiter: char) -> Vec<T>
where
    T: std::str::FromStr,
    <T as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let stdin = stdin.lock();
    read_vector(count, delimiter, stdin)
}
```

Because of the absence of such things as template specialisations and default arguments, I had to write more code than I would in C++ and found myself duplicating so many things. I would like to see how true Rust programmers would solve the problem.

Comment: This doesn't even meet your own requirements: *"all possible streams"* — you require that it implement `BufRead`!

Comment: @Shepmaster I implied entities similar to Stdin (so it seems that ReadBuf is what I wanted to support).I'm not quite good at the terminology of Rust, I just used the term from C++, probably it's not 100% correct here.